# Append to String a Signed Int (Converted to Bytes) in Big Endian

Tags: c++

I have a 4 byte integer (signed), and (i) I want to reverse the byte order, (ii) I want to store the bytes (i.e. the 4 bytes) as bytes of the string. I am working in C++. In order to reverse the byte order in Big Endian, I was using the ntohl, but I cannot use that due the fact that my numbers can be also negative.

Example:

```
int32_t a = -123456;
string s;
s.append(reinterpret_cast<char*>(reinterpret_cast<void*>(&a))); // int to byte
```

Further, when I am appending these data, it seems that I am appending 8 bytes instead of 4, why?
I need to use the append (I cannot use memcpy or something else).
Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: `std::string` is intended for textual data – if you want to store binary data then `std::vector<unsigned char>` or `std::vector<signed char>` or probably even better vectors of fixed length types from `<cstdint>` (`uint8_t`, `int8_t`) are usually more appropriate.

Comment: Although `std::string` supports NUL characters in the middle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was using the ntohl, but I cannot use that due the fact that my numbers can be also negative.

It's unclear why you think that negative number would be a problem. It's fine to convert negative numbers with `ntohl`.

> ```
> s.append(reinterpret_cast<char*>(reinterpret_cast<void*>(&a)));
> ```

`std::string::append(char*)` requires that the argument points to a null terminated string. An integer is not null terminated (unless it happens to contain a byte that incidentally represents a null terminator character). As a result of violating this requirement, the behaviour of the program is undefined.

> Do you have any suggestion?

To fix this bug, you can use the `std::string::append(char*, size_type)` overload instead:

```
s.append(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&a), sizeof a);
```

> ```
> reinterpret_cast<char*>(reinterpret_cast<void*>
> ```

The inner cast to `void*` is redundant. It makes no difference.

Comment: Thanks for the comment about the ntohl (I did not know that it can works also for negative numbers). Anyway, if I do this s.append(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&a), sizeof a), I receive an error like: double free or corruption

Comment: @CipherX Your program has undefined behaviour caused by something else.